# How to create a legend in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a regression problem and I want to plot 3 DataFrames.  I don't know how to set the labels for the Dataframes.  I want blue->ACTUAL, green->SVR, red->MLR.

What is wrong with the code?

```
ax1 = y_test[1800:1900].plot(color='blue', linewidth=3)
predicted_y[1800:1900].plot(color='green', linewidth=3, ax =ax1)
predicted_y1[1800:1900].plot(color='red', linewidth=3, ax=ax1)
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05),   prop={'size':35})
plt.show()
```

I plot this and it shows me all colors with 0 values.

Comment: This should probably be on stackoverflow

Comment: Have you tried passing label as argument, y_test[1800:1900].plot(color='blue', linewidth=3, label="ACTUAL").

Comment: -1 ... it should not be here. maybe stackoverflow

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question. Good clarity might help with it. However, being able to visualize data using a software, is a question that this group could help with.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you add labels to your plots:

```
ax1 = y_test[1800:1900].plot(color='blue', linewidth=3, label = 'ACTUAL')
predicted_y[1800:1900].plot(color='green', linewidth=3, ax =ax1, label = 'SVR')
predicted_y1[1800:1900].plot(color='red', linewidth=3, ax=ax1, label = 'MVR')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05),   prop={'size':35})
plt.show()
```

Comment: plt.legend(('ACTUAL', 'SVR', 'MLR'), loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05), prop={'size':30})
    plt.show()